# Error 1366: Incorrect string value when inserting strings into MariaDB

Tags: mysql, go, mariadb

I have MariaDB table that has index `VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci'` type. I have a string in Go that I cut to 10 characters, if it is longer, to insert into/update this table. I cut the string as:

```
if len(value) > 10 {
  value = value[:10]
}
```

Right now I have encountered an issue with string that ends with `š` character. MariaDB throws error: `Error 1366: Incorrect string value: '\\xC5'`. Looking up unicode tables, this character is represented as `\xc5\xa1` which makes me believe the cutting of the string somehow makes the string indigestible for the database?

I would like to avoid handling utf8/unicode in my code because that would require going through all database methods and massaging all strings. And I do not believe this is necessary since i have never needed it before. So I think the issue lies somewhere else but am not sure where.

I tried to switch the collation to `utf8mb4_general_ci` but that did not help either.

Interestingly, if I edit the column directly with HeidiSQL, the string saves just fine.Which leads me to believe this might be a driver issue. I am using the `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`, as always. So I would not expect issues but, who knows...

Comment: Incorrect charset. Check charset settings (`show variables like 'char%';`).

Comment: @Akina character_set_client, character_set_connection, character_set_results are utf8mb4 and character_set_database, character_set_server, character_set_system are utf8mb3. this is official mariadb installation, one month old with one dev db.

Comment: Go provides some another charset, not UTFx. Either correct Go settings or apply CONVERT() to provided data.

Comment: @Akina Go's strings are UTF8. there is nothing to convert.

Comment: UTF8 string whose first byte is `0c5h`? Hangul Syllables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which makes me believe the cutting of the string somehow makes the string indigestible for the database?

Cutting strings by sub-slicing as `value[:10]` (and measuring length with `len` for that matter) is **always** a mistake if your program has any chance of dealing with multi-byte characters. That's because indexing a string operates on its bytes, which may or may not be part of multi-byte encoding.

As you found out, the character [`š`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0161) is encoded in UTF-8 as `\xc5\xa1`. If these two bytes appear in your `value` string right at index `9` and `10` your index expression `[:10]` corrupts the data.

The character sets `utf8mb3` and `utf8mb4` only restrict the range of admitted UTF-8 to respectively 3-byte and 4-byte characters, but `\xc5` is not valid UTF-8 to begin with, so it gets rejected either way.

In MariaDB a column with data type `VARCHAR(N)` counts *characters* (as specified by the collation). You want to cut your `value` string at the tenth character, instead of at the tenth byte.

> I would like to avoid handling utf8/unicode in my code

You are already admitting UTF-8 by declaring the MariaDB collation as `utf8mb3`. It's only logical that you properly handle input data in your code as UTF-8. To cut at the n-th character (or `rune`, which in Go represents a Unicode code point) you can use something like:

```
// count the runes
if utf8.RuneCountInString(value) > 10 {
  // convert string to rune slice
  chars := []rune(value)
  // index the rune slice and convert back to string
  value = string(chars[:10])
}
```

This won't corrupt UTF-8 encoding, **however** keep in mind it does more allocs and doesn't account for composed characters, e.g. when the joiner `200D` is involved.